# Code snippets feel inconsistent

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Could we combine "Expand snippet" and "Full page" into a single and consistent experience?

If not then at least improve the general wonkiness?

---

**Expand snippet**

I can run code in this mode, great!

[image]

---

I have to hide my results in order to close this window?

[image]

---

So if I run my code first then I can get a full screen view of the results only?

Why can I not expand the snippet after running it unless I hide the results?

[image]

Comment: The position of the close button in fullscreen has always annoyed me. Every time I have to search for it.

Comment: @Nick I always felt that something was off about snippets but never analyzed what it was exactly. I recently posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413575/2191572) and while debugging my own answer I got lost and had to refresh the page to exit the snippet because I didn't realize I had to "Hide results" first.

Comment: @Nick Snippets were introduced in 2014 so I finally understand why 2014 experienced so much negativity on Stack Overflow, heh.

Comment: Another Stack Snippet FR that can be ignored for 6-8. Wish we could get this thing updated...

Comment: @HereticMonkey 6-8 what, "business years"? 

Comment: Well, the [official meme is "weeks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/194720) but we've taken it to mean any sufficiently abstract period of time :)